# "Cleartext HTTP traffic to www.android.com not permitted" when trying httpurlconnection in Android Studio

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am getting the error in the title line.  I have tried to overcome it by trying the suggestions I have found at stack overflow including adding to AndroidManifest.xml this:

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

and then creating res/xml/network_security_config.xml containing this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.android.com</domain>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

For reference the calling code in the Activity is as follows:

```
try {
       url = new URL("http://www.android.com/");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
```

but no luck so far.  My goal is to make a simple connection here as a test.  How to fix this?  TIA.

Comment: Forgot to mention, also added this to AndroidManifest.xml:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to you app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest ...>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <application
            ...
            android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" // this line.
            ...>
            ...
        </application>
 </manifest>
```

Comment: Thanks Raj! That fixed things.  I now have a question about reading the stream once the HTTP connection is made, but will start a new post since it is a new topic.